# How to write decimal values to csv file in qt

Tags: qt, csv, save, hex

I have written a piece of code that should save doubles in an csv file. Here it is:

```
QString fileName = QFileDialog::getSaveFileName(this,tr("Save Logger Data"), "",tr("LoggerData(*.csv);;All Files (*)"));
if (fileName.isEmpty())
{
    return;
}
else
{
    QFile file(fileName);
    if (!file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly))
    {
        QMessageBox::information(this, tr("Unable to open file"), file.errorString());
        return;
    }
    QDataStream out(&file);

    out << data1 << "/t" << data2 << "/n";
}
```

Here, data1 and data2 are doubles. When I open the savefile I only see weird characters (I asume they are hexadecimal values??). How can I change my code so it saves doubles instead of hex?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

QDataStream is not the right class for this.  For text output use QTextStream instead.